# Hunspell を WPF で使用したいのですが、初期化に失敗するようです

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF で HunSpell の ラッパークラス NHunspellWrapper を使用していますが、

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // スペルチェック
   var hunspell = new NHunspellWrapper();
}
```

で呼び出される

```
public NHunspellWrapper() : this("en_US.aff", "en_US.dic", null, new SpellingFormBasic())
{

}

/// <param name="affFile">"en_us.aff"</param>
/// <param name="dicFile">"en_us.dic"</param>
public NHunspellWrapper(string affFile, string dicFile, ISpellingControl textEditor, ISpellingWindow spellForm)
{
    try
    {
        hunspell = new Hunspell(affFile, dicFile);
        var chk = hunspell.Spell("with");           <- false が返る
            ：
```

hunspell は、null ではありませんが、辞書ファイルが読めていないか、初期化に失敗しているような気がします。
根拠はありませんが・・・

この Hunspell のサンプルは、WinForm ようのもので WPF のものを探しても見つかりませんでした。

[image]

HunspellWrapper コンポーネント spellingWorker が WinForm では作られるようですが、WPF では作られないようですね。

WPF でHunspell のコンポーネントを使用する方法ってどのようにするのでしょうか？

環境 Windows10 VS2015 C# WPF

Comment: さらに大元のNHunspellサンプルにもWPF用の例は無いようです。[NHunspell Spellcheck-Hyphen-Thesaurus](https://sourceforge.net/p/nhunspell/code/ci/default/tree/NHunspellSamples/) 標準のSpellChekで代替してみてはどうでしょう？ [方法: テキスト編集コントロールでスペル チェックを有効にする](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-enable-spell-checking-in-a-text-editing-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), [SpellCheck クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.spellcheck?view=net-5.0), [WPF の textBox で SpellCheck をしたい](https://teratail.com/questions/243588)

Answer (score 1):

> NHunspell Spellcheck-Hyphen-Thesaurus 標準のSpellChekで代替してみてはどうでしょう

これでうまく行けるようですね。

https://sourceforge.net/p/nhunspell/code/ci/default/tree/NHunspellSamples/CSharpConsoleSamples/Program.cs#l51

上記のサイトより

```
using (var hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_us.dic"))
{

    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("CustomWords-en_US.txt");
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        hunspell.Add(line);
    }
```

の形式を直接実行する形でうまくいっているように見えます。

ありがとうございました。